# I have nested serializer's and want to create an instance for the same by overriding the create method.

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have two models for my Quiz App as below:-

```
class Answer_Options(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And

```
class Quiz_Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, default=None, null=True, related_name='questions')
    q_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    possible_answers = models.ManyToManyField(Answer_Options)
    selected = models.ForeignKey(Answer_Options, related_name="selected", default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    correct = models.ForeignKey(Answer_Options, related_name="correct", default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Now I would like to make serializers for these above models like below:-

```
class Answer_OptionsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer_Options
        fields = ('url', 'text')
```

and for the Quiz_Question like this:-

```
class Quiz_QuestionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    possible_answers = Answer_OptionsSerializer(many=True)
    correct = Answer_OptionsSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz_Question
        fields = ('url', 'quiz', 'q_type', 'text', 'possible_answers', 'selected', 'correct')
```

Now the problem that I face is how can I override the `create()` method so that I can save the `possible_answers` for that question and also save the `selected` as well as the `correct` option where the `selected` and the `correct` options must be values from the list of `possible_answers`. For example if my `possible_answers` list is ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] then the value of `selected` as well as `correct` fields must be either `'A', 'B', 'C' or 'D'`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way to do so like this:-

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        possible_answers_data = validated_data.pop('possible_answers')
        selected_answers_data = validated_data.pop('selected')
        correct_answers_data = validated_data.pop('correct')
        quiz_question = Quiz_Question.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if possible_answers_data:
            for answer in possible_answers_data:
                answer, created  = Answer_Options.objects.get_or_create(text=answer['text'])     
                if (answer.text == correct_answers_data['text']):
                    print answer.text
                    quiz_question.correct = answer                               
                quiz_question.possible_answers.add(answer)
        return quiz_question
```

Comment: But my quiz_question.correct = answer is not getting saved and I do not get any errors or exceptions as well.